# twitter bootstrap align tables side by side

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there anyway I can lineup tables side by side in twitter bootstrap, I want to achieve this:

[image]

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind just Googled that the span* class in twitter bootstrap is already depreciated and replaced by the col-md-* function and it's other counterparts.

I have solved my problem by wrapping the two tables in

```
<div class="col-md-*">
```

I have used this for the first table:

```
<div class="col-md-3"> 
    <table>....</table>
</div>
```

and this for the second table

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <table>....</table>
</div>
```